# Delivery date checker for e-commerce website

Tags: sql

I’ve made an e-commerce website where administrators can specify the number of deliveries they can make on any one day.

I’ve written a SQL statement that then finds all delivery dates, finds any matching orders on those dates, and then returns any where the remaining “slots” are greater than zero (i.e. available). The statement looks like this:

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    `delivery_date`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `orders` WHERE DATE(`orders`.`created_at`) = `delivery_dates`.`delivery_date`) AS `order_count`
FROM
    `delivery_dates`
HAVING
    SUM(`delivery_limit` - `order_count`) > 0;
```

It works, but is this optimal? I’m not sure on the inner `SELECT`, and the `HAVING` statements.